# encoding mail with utf-8

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm sure to answer my question will be quite easy - but I am getting crazy with my code and don't know why nothing works.

Well, first, here is the script:

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['submit']){
if(empty($_REQUEST['name']) || empty($_REQUEST['email'])
|| empty($_REQUEST['comments']))
{
echo "Bitte gehen Sie <a href=\"javascript:history.back();\">
zurück</a> und füllen Sie alle Felder aus!";
}
else{
$Mailnachricht="Sie haben eine Anfrage über(ueber) ihr Kontaktformular erhalten:\n";
$Mailnachricht .= "Name: ".$_REQUEST['name']."\n".
"E-Mail: ".$_REQUEST['email']."\n".
"Datum: ".date("d.m.Y H:i")."\n".
"\n\n".$_REQUEST['comments']."\n";
$Mailbetreff = "Kontaktanfrage von: ".$_REQUEST['name'];
mail($Empfaenger, $Mailbetreff, $Mailnachricht, "From: "
.$_REQUEST['email']);
echo "Danke! Ihre Mail wurde erfolgreich versendet. <br>
<a href=\"javascript:history.back();\">Zurück</a>";
}
}
else
{
echo "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. Hier können Sie eine <a href=\"contact.php\">Anfrage</a> an uns senden.";
}
?>
```

So, how can I set UTF-8 here?

Thanks for your help, I don't know who to do this.

**Look at the answer below!**

Comment: **Why did the pre-poster delete his comment?** This also doesn't want to work and I don't know why. I am searching the web for hours now and didn't find anything that is working well.

Comment: The best thing to do is not use `mail()`.  Use something like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer to handle building all the MIME encoding headers for you.

Comment: I do not want to rewrite the form I just want to know how to set the utf-8!

Comment: Add `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8` to your email headers

Comment: @Intera This is much more of a complicated problem than you realize.

Comment: @Brad And how do i deal with this problem?

Comment: @Intera I already made two possible suggestions.  Generating the correct headers is a very difficult problem.  You could literally spend months on it, or use an existing class and swap out 3 or 4 lines of code.

Comment: @Brad Can you or anyone else help me how to use the existing solutions?

Comment: @Intera Not without knowing what you've tried and where you're stuck.  Start with the documentation and post a new question if you have one.  http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction.html

Comment: @Brad Now I found a much easier solution! Without using anithing from another people. So please have a look at my answer and tell me what you think of this

Answer (score 0):

Well, nobody answered, another 5 hours searching for a solution and now I have one:

```html
mail($Empfaenger, $Mailbetreff, $Mailnachricht, "From: "
.$_REQUEST['email'] ."\r\n".'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"');
```

Change this in the previous code snippet and your mail will be sent with utf-8.